# Process continues running after main thread has terminated?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, dll, native

I'll start by saying I do not have a lot of experience in troubleshooting multi-threading problems. So a lot of what I've read about debugging race conditions, dead locks, live locks, etc. are strictly theoretical to me.

I have this .NET application that is making use of a dynamically loaded native win32 dll. If the dll is never loaded the application terminates without a problem. However, if the dll is loaded then when the user exits the application the UI disappears but the process never terminates.

I've turned on native code debugging in the project settings so I can see all the threads that are running. When the user closes the application window the main thread appears to terminate. I know this because if I perform a *Break All* in the Threads windows in Visual Studio the main thread is re-categorized as a worker thread and there is no call stack available for it. There are 20 other threads still active, all with call stacks. I've looked through the call stacks for all of these threads and nothing sticks out at me (there's no mention of the dll in any of the call stacks).

What steps can I take to narrow down the cause of this problem? Are there any additional tools I should be using to help pin point the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that some of your Foreground Threads are still alive. Unlike Background Threads, Foreground Threads keeps the process alive.

You should either use Background Threads or Stop your Foregrounds Threads to be able to exit the process gracefully.

Windows application will automatically exit when all of its thread(s) are stopped.

As you said

> If the dll is never loaded the application terminates without a
>   problem

I'm assuming all the running threads are unmanaged threads(not created by clr). There is no concept of background threads in native code. All threads must be terminated to terminate the process.

You must find a way to signal all threads to exit in that library. See if you have any api exposed for that.

If you don't find anything, you've got a "Sledge Hammer" approach. i.e Terminate the process with `Environment.Exit` which works almost always. Be sure you use this approach as a last resort as this can corrupt the process state.

Comment: The library in question was written in house but all the threads were being created by third party libraries that were statically linked into the dll. Rather than attempt to babysit the thread management of third party code it was easier to use the "sledge hammer".